# In what sense do Bayesian models simulate observation?

Tags: bayesian, simulation, generative-models

Could you verify that i understand the author correctly here? New to Bayes.

> [...] These assumptions [the prior and the likelihood] also allow us to simulate the observations that the model implies. They allow this, because likelihood functions work in both directions.
> Given a realized observation, the likelihood function says how plausible the observation is.
> And given only the parameters, the likelihood defines a distribution of possible observations that we can sample from, to simulate observation. In this way, Bayesian models are always generative, capable of simulating predictions. Many non-Bayesian models are also generative, but many are not.
> -- [McElreath R., Statistical Rethinking^2](https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:8kN9J_ljzZAJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=ChUhx1wnEMmimhqVvJM:ABFrs3wAAAAAZL-TpJMkqCsTqu6FGPux5s2bZTs&scisig=ABFrs3wAAAAAZL-TpJXGidDjBoheKlX5uzX-gt8&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en)

---

Let's say i trained some model of **P(A|B)**. Please let me know if i'm correct in interpreting the following statements.

> *Given a realized observation, the likelihood function says how plausible the observation is.*

This just refers to the "forward" **P(B|A)** that i chose to use when conditioning the prior on every data point?

> *Given only the parameters, the likelihood defines a distribution of possible observations that we can sample from, to simulate observation*:

Now, turning it around, if i sample from the posterior (via something like the [PPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution)), the factor that would have mostly determined the shape of *whatever i trained* and am now sampling *from* would be the likelihood **P(B|A)**. So in *this* sense, i have tap of synthetic data which represents the target **P(A|B)** as accurately as my conditioning *up-to-now* has been?

Comment: The notations $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$ are intended for events, not for random variables.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the statement is the following:

If you fix the data, the likelihood $P(B|A)$ tells you the most likely parameters that generated the data. However, once you have estimated the parameters, you have a fully specified distribution from which you can sample synthetic data.

In the Bayesian framework, the prior $P(A)$ allows us to treat the parameter $\theta$ as a random variable, injecting information into the estimation which no longer depends only on the observed data (likelihood). So when you have the trained $P(A|B)$, you have a generative model.

If the posterior has a nice closed form, like when you use conjugate priors, you have a new distribution that factors in the data and the prior knowledge, updating the parameters and giving you a distribution of them. Otherwise, you resort to numerical methods (like MCMC) to get the solution.

In both cases, when you have the parameters' distribution, you can plug them in and get the data that the modeled process would generate. If everything is correct, the generated and real data should be compatible, indicating that your model reproduces reality correctly.

I hope this helps